# Python Tkinter .insert() method - print data on new line in text box

Tags: python, tkinter, insert

Using tkinter and python to create a simple GUI with textbox.
I'm trying to revise the script below so that it prints each line of cleaned data from `unique_data` on a new line in my textbox. Right now it prints the cleaned data all onto one line.

`fp` is a global filepath earlier in the class. IT reads that raw data and filters out numerical only bits and whitespaces so that it goes from this:

> ABC/DEF//5GH//678//

to this:

> ABC, DEF, 5GH,

The function for `unique_data` was taken from another working script, but I'd like for it to instead of printing the data, to write that data in a text box defined `txt_edit`.

How can I adjust the last line so that it reads and print the data in `unique_data` into the `txt_edit` text box?

```
    def split_lines(fp, delimiter, remove='^[0-9.]+$'):
        with open(fp, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            clean_list = []
            for line in file:
                tokens = line.split(delimiter)
                tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
                clean_list.append(list(filter(lambda e: e.strip(), tokens)))
            txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            unique_data = {}
            for item in clean_list:
                key = str(item)
                if not unique_data.get(key):
                    unique_data[key] = 1, item
                else:
                    unique_data[key] = (unique_data[key][0] + 1), item
            for k, v in unique_data.items():
                txt_edit.insert(tk.END, unique_data(f"{v[0]}x {v[1]}")) # EDIT ME!!
```

Comment: assuming that unique_data is dictionary and not a function: txt_edit.insert(tk.END, f"{v[0]}x {v[1]}")

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi this works! Although it's all on one line, can I adjust this to have the new data print on a new line?

Comment: It was supposed to add to the end due to tk.END, unless you want v[1] to be added to a new line you can use newline character \n like: f"{v[0]}x \n {v[1]}"

Comment: Ah I got it working! `txt_edit.insert(tk.END, f"{v[1]}x {v[0]} \n"` This outputs what I'd like to see.